# Dynamic Table Name in LINQ SQL using VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, linq

I need to do something like the following:

```
Dim sampleRespondentsIDs As New List(Of Integer)()

Dim Tablename As String = "Responses" + "GBR"

sampleRespondentsIDs = (From r In db.GetTable(Tablename) 
                        Where r.CountryID = 1)
                       .Select(Function(r) r.RespondentID).Distinct().ToList()
```

I have been searching for ages but nothing seems to fit what I'm asking for - I have loaded ResponsesGBR into Entity Framework and could reference it directly but I really want to be able to swap between Response tables based on Country

Comment: Are you using Entities or Linq-to-SQL?

Comment: Why haven't you got one `Responses` table with a country id field?

Comment: I would love to use 1 responses table with a country id field but I am dealing with 30 million records vertically stacked in SQL Server 2005 and my cross tab screen takes over 10 seconds to load. And yes it's indexed.

Comment: Nathan - I've loaded the table "ResponsesGBR" into my Entity Framework model *.edmx and I'm trying to reference it using LINQ. I could replace in my code above "GetTable(Tablename)" with "ResponsesGBR" and it would work. I hope this answers your question